# Definition of an array of floats in c#

Tags: c#

I have an array that worked when it was defined as doubles. As I am passing them to a Vector3 (for some use in Unity) they need to be defined as floats, which I cannot seem to do at the point of definition. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
    private float[] coords_x = { -13.3, -48.2, -53.3, -68, -74, -78.9, -79.1, -72.7 };
    private float[] coords_y = { -54.8, -78.3, -81.7, -82, -76.9, -69.2, -54.4, -40.8 };
    private float[] coords_theta = { 124, 124, 115, 96, 50, 0, -25.3, -25.3 };
```

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)?

Comment: You need to append an `f` to all of the values (e.g. `-13.3f`) to create float literals.

Comment: Simpler example: `float f = -13.3;` won't compile, because the literal `-13.3` is of type `double`, not `float`. You'd need `float f = -13.3f;`